# Virtualenv returning a 'No such file or directory...' error

Tags: python, virtualenv

The command `virtualenv --no-site-packages env/` produces the following error stack trace:

```
    The --no-site-packages flag is deprecated; it is now the default behavior.
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools.............done.
Installing pip...
  Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command /home/zach/School/CS...env/bin/easy_install /usr/local/lib/pytho...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 928, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1042, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 640, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 966, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1239, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and Python 2.7.

EDIT:
Figured it out.

I originally installed it with pip, so I uninstalled via pip and that reinstalled via `apt-get`.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 12.04 and installing virtualenv via apt-get didn't fix the issue, but this one helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339410/unable-to-do-herokus-python-tutorial-within-dropbox-folder

Comment: For Mac: `pip3 install pipenv --upgrade` worked for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

virtualenv looks to be trying to install pip using easy_install from a local archive. Can you verify that it exists at `/usr/local/lib/pytho...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz` ?

You may want to ensure that you have pip properly install beforehand. Try: `easy_install -U pip` first.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my suspicion was, hence reinstalling through apt-get. Thanks though.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same on debian. Upgrade `python-virtualenv` resolves the problem.

```
apt-get upgrade python-virtualenv
```

Comment: you mean apt-get install python-virtualenv. This will upgrade only the virtualenv package.

Answer (score 4):

In mac run `pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper` to install virtualenv.

Comment: this also gives bad interpreter error 
`-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the path to easy_install does not have spaces in it: /home/zach/School/CS...env/bin/easy_install

Answer (score 0):

If you are Debian user, then this command should resolve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade python-virtualenv
```